# ¿Como crear columnas invisbles en MariaDB?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Dentro del gestor de bases de datos mariaDB, podemos al momento de construir una tabla, indicar el tipo de dato que se espera recibir, así como su `longitud` y si esta debe ser o no `NULL`.

> Sin embargo en gestores como `Oracle` podemos definir en la versión
>   `12c`, a través de la siguiente sintáxis podemos definir columnas
>   `invisibles`

```
CREATE TABLE data(
  id NUMBER,
  name NUMBER,
  DNI NUMBER INVISBLE);
```

Las características que ofrecen la declaración de columnas como esta son:

1. No son visibles en un `SELECT *`
2. Solo van a aparecer cuando se nombre la columna en la sintáxis del `SELECT`

La duda es ¿cómo lograr lo mismo en **mariaDB Server**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del gestor de bases de datos MariaDB, desde la versión 10.3.3 podemos tener esta característica disponible.

A través del siguiente ejemplo muestro como declarar una columna de tipo `invisible`

Esta es la declaración de una tabla con columnas regulares

```
MariaDB [blog]> CREATE TABLE demo(
    -> id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> name VARCHAR(22) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    -> features JSON NOT NULL)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Ahora justo después de la columna `name` quiero agregar una columna llamada `token` de tipo `VARCHAR`que será invisible

```
MariaDB [blog]> ALTER TABLE demo ADD COLUMN token VARCHAR(100) INVISIBLE NOT NULL 
DEFAULT 'No asignado' AFTER name;
```

Nota importante, una columna de tipo invisible en `mariaDB` se debe declarar forozosamente con un valor por `deafult`, de lo contrario devolverá un error indicando lo que ya he mencionado

Ahora si revisamos con la sentencia `DESCRIBE` la tabla demo, veremos lo siguiente

```
MariaDB [blog]> DESCRIBE demo;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default     | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------+----------------+
| id       | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL        | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(22)  | NO   | UNI | NULL        |                |
| token    | varchar(100) | NO   |     | No asignado | INVISIBLE      |
| features | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL        |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------+----------------+
```

Donde como podemos observar en la columna `extra` nos indica que token también posee una característica o atributo extra llamado invisible

Ahora demos de alta un registro

```
MariaDB [blog]> INSERT INTO demo(name, features)
    -> VALUES
    -> ('alfa', '{"cool": "true"}');
```

Hagamos un `SELECT *` a la tabla `demo` para ver la información que contiene

```
MariaDB [blog]> SELECT * FROM demo;
+----+------+------------------+
| id | name | features         |
+----+------+------------------+
|  1 | alfa | {"cool": "true"} |
+----+------+------------------+
```

Como observamos la columna `token` mantiene su condición de invisible, en tanto no la declaremos de manera explícita en el `SELECT`, de la siguiente manera en cuyo caso será visible

```
MariaDB [blog]> SELECT id, name, token, features FROM demo;
+----+------+-------------+------------------+
| id | name | token       | features         |
+----+------+-------------+------------------+
|  1 | alfa | No asignado | {"cool": "true"} |
+----+------+-------------+------------------+
```

> Como puedes observar en el ejemplo anterior ahora no solo es vivisble
>   la columna `token` si no que además al no declararle un valor, tomó el
>   que le dimos por `DEFAULT`